# How to add 1 select field onclick per click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a select field multiple times depending on the number of clicks the user makes. A toggle or show/hide function will only work for 1 select field.

How would I be able to do that?

e.g: 1 click = add 1 select field

```
<select name='' id='' class="">
   <option value='en-us'>USA</option>
   <option value='de-de'>Germany</option>
   <option value='en-in'>India</option>
   <option value='en-gb'>United Kingdom</option>
   <option value='en-au'>Australia</option>
</select> <br>
<button id='add-countries'>add more countries</button>
```

I have prepared a sample html for this: http://jsfiddle.net/stan255/Wh274/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. jQuery is used here for simplicity, but is not required.

```
<div id="template">
  <select name='' id='' class="">
    ...
  </select>
</div>
<button id='add-countries'>add more countries</button>

var $template = $('#template');
$('#add-countries').on('click', function () {
  $(this).before($template.clone());
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wh274/3/.

Note that this does not account for assigning unique names to each `<select>` so you will need to add that logic or account for it on the server side.

Comment: Can I choose not to your the var function and immediately assign the id to the select field instead?

Comment: That should work the same way. I added the wrapper `<div>` to negate the need for the `<br>` element.

Answer (score 0):

if you could javascript (jQuery)

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('button#add-countries').click(function(){
            newName = prompt('Please input new name');
            newAttr = prompt('Please input new short name');
            newItem = '<option value="'+newAttr+'">'+newName+'</option>';
            $('select').append(newItem);
        });
    })
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('button#add-countries').click(function(){
            alert($('select option:selected').val())
        });
    })
</script>
```